# What is merge doing here...? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can you explain me what function of merge method here?

```
it "should reject email addresses identical up to case" do
 upcased_email = @attr[:email].upcase
 User.create!(@attr.merge(:email => upcased_email))
 user_with_duplicate_email = User.new(@attr)
 user_with_duplicate_email.should_not be_valid
end
```

How it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply merging the email key back into the hash map (once its value has been lower cased):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge

Comment: so after merging @attr will contain what?

Comment: The upper cased version of whatever the email address was before. (Accidentally said lower cased in my answer). Have you tried echoing out the value before and after?

Comment: before code must be @attr = { :name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com" }, the thing is i don't understand what result of @attr.merge(:email => upcased_email) will be

Comment: That's the output of echoing @attr.merge(:email => upcased_email)? I'm quite rusty at Ruby, so now I'm thinking my answer might be completely wrong >.<.  Edit: Ah!  Just output it the same way you output the other one.  Save it to a temporary variable if necessary.